# jpeg compression: necessity of dividing input image into 8x8 blocks

Tags: image-processing, dct, image-compression, jpeg

For jpeg compression, is it necessary to divide the input image into 8x8 blocks and perform a DCT on each of the 64 blocks?
If your input image is mxn, could you just have 1 mxn DCT coefficient matrix?  Would jpeg compression still work the same?

Answer (score 2):

let us first make this clearer: "is it necessary to divide the input image into 8x8 blocks and perform a DCT on each of the 64 blocks". We divide the picture into blocks of size $8\times 8$, with 64 pixels each. Then we apply the 2D DCT on those blocks. One does not divide an image into 64 blocks globally. The number of blocks depends on the image size.

So, the most widely applied JPEG scheme is on $8\times 8$ pixel blocks. Some extensions outside the standard have used other sizes like $4\times 4$  or $16\times 16$ blocks (I remember using them working on image compression for Earth observation satellites).

And yes, you could turn $m\times n$ pictures into an 1 $m\times n$ DCT coefficient matrix. Whether this yields better compression can be discussed, because:

- there are  several ways to turn a 2D  matrix into a  1D one
- the  $n\times n$ idea uses the notion that image  data can be stationary, at least locally.

Without blocking, there is a risk that your data is not so stationary,  and  you will pay that in DCT coefficients encoding

Comment: I think that the core, baseline jpeg is limited to 8x8 DCTs. A MCU can be 16x16 if 4:2:0 encoding is used, but then it is further subdivided into 4 8x8 luma blocks, one 8x8 Cb block and one 8x8 Cr block. I dont know about possible annexes and modern developments

Comment: My memory is possibly leaking.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want to exploit local statistics (small block size) and to have long runs of zero in your run-length encoding (large blocks). Large lossy transform coding could possible show artifacts far away from high contrast edges. 8x8 was probably considered a reasonable trade off back in ~1990 with typical image resolutions and available compute.

You could probably easily redesign JPEG to use 4x4 or 16x16 DCTs. Or you could use a modern codec like HEIF (based on h26x intra) where a multitude of block and transform layouts are possible.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, using the 8x8 macroblocks is necessary, because if you did it any other way, you would not get a JPEG.

Comment: I believe it would be greatly beneficial to add some more information to your answer. For example, clarifying why one wouldn't "get a JPEG" in a different case as well as some information on the coding of the JPEG that dictates the use of an $8 \times 8$ block.

Comment: @ZaellixA The JPEG standard says the blocks must be 8x8. So it is not possible for it to have a standard JPEG file with any other DCT block size. To be a JPEG file, it must be encoded according to the standard.

Comment: To be honest, I do not know much about image processing (apart from the very basics) and it is not a primary interest of mine. The comment was targeted towards encouraging you to provide some more information to make your suggestion clear. For example, to someone like me (ignorant to the JPEG standard) it is not clear why this is the case. I still believe you should enrich your answer with some supporting information and possibly an example or a link to the relevant part of the standard.